# Rackspace, heartbeat ip failover

Tags: server, failover

I have tested `tomcat specific clustering` with apache `mod_jk` and `mod_proxy` on ubuntu local VMs for our website high availability and load balancing. The real servers are hosted by `Rackspace cloud` server provider and I should implement this on cloud servers once completely done. I tested tomcat clustering with 1 load balancer and 2 web servers. As single load balancer is again a `single point of failure`, I'm trying to add one more LB as slave.

In Rackspace there is an option `Load Balancers` and [here](http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/index.php/Configuring_a_Cloud_Load_Balancer) is the link which guides how setting up load balancer which I am not sure to setup because of some doubts as I never did this before anytime.

I heard Rackspace offers to `share an ip` between computers, is that so?, then I can use this option.

I am trying `heartbeat` configuration on the load balancers and the way I followed from the [link](http://library.linode.com/linux-ha/ip-failover-heartbeat-pacemaker-ubuntu-10.04) seems to work for a site. I have the following doubts here:

- I think I should use `public ip` address in the place of `virtual/floating` ip which is shared and also to which the site domain is pointed, is that so?.
- How could I configure heartbeat for multiple web sites as we have more than one site hosting?.
- I will specify public/shared ip as virtual ip by `eth0:0` in the network interface file on both the load balancers. Do you really think it works flawless even if specified the public ip as virtual ip with eth0:0 interface without any interruption?

Again I just gave a glance of other links [link1](http://www.zivtech.com/blog/setting-ip-failover-heartbeat-and-pacemaker-ubuntu-lucid), [link2](http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/index.php/IP_Failover_-_Setup_and_Installing_Heartbeat) and got confused which one to follow to host multiple webistes with ip failover. Does anyone tell me which link suits best for my requirement?

Finally my goal is to have `ip-failover`(master slave) for load balancers and need help on configuring heartbeat for multiple websites(`may be pointing site domains to shared ip does the work?`).

If we successed, we can share the success just by telling you 'thank you very much'. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Anybody please?

Comment: May be you can have more answers at http://superuser.com/ . Also I couldn't tell what is the question and how is it related to Ubuntu?

Answer (score -3):

I work at Rackspace and would be happy to help out here! Email me at mw at Rackspace dot com any time.

mw @ Rackspace . com. Email any time!

Comment: Happy to hear!, first I need your mail id!

Comment: Could we have the resolution posted back here for future users?

Comment: @Marco ceppi: Definitely once I got it resolved, if nobody answered , I'll post back for future users

Comment: This guy didn't reply at all for the mail I sent!